# Does the REQ level go up equally for all players?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

During a warzone game, does the REQ level go up equally for all players/teams or is it an individual scoring system?

If it is based on team points, at how many points are levels unlocked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REQ level doesn't go up equally for all players (and as far as I know isn't tied to your team score). I've witnessed this while playing in a party where the best performers get clearly better REQ levels (and better weapons etc.) before me.

So there in fact is an individual scoring system where REQ level goes up by killing enemies and AIs. There are also some team based growing of REQ level since capturing bases, clearing your own core in the beginning (not in all maps but in e.g. Stormbreak) boosts your REQ level even if you weren't there when it was captured.

To your last question: since the level is tied to both personal and some team based achieving, level can't be tied to team score.

Also when you have reached a certain REQ level lets say 3 and taken an Energy Sword and then died with it. You can't right away take another one because now you have used 3 available energy and you need to get your energy level back to 3. This energy however does climb up just by passing time.

Ps. Someone could complete this answer by stating how many spartan kills, AI kills, legendary AI kills, caps each leveling up requires if anyone has ever acquired such knowledge.

Comment: You misunderstand the question; i am not asking about REQ points, i am asking about the REQ levels that unlock during an active game which allow you to buy higher level items during the game

Comment: Ok @Vahx, now I understood the problem and edited a lot to better answer the question.